# How do I use my new custom view in my ListView?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I'm new to Android so please forgive my ignorance~ I have a few questions that I haven't been able to find the answers to.

I've created a new view called `ImageTapView`. The idea is that when you tap the view, an info overlay would appear. Here's the class (just barebones right now):

```
package com.mysite;

public class ImageTapView extends View {
    public ImageTapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }
    private void init(Context context){

    }
    public void onClick(){

    }    
}
```

So far I've:

1. Created the custom class file
2. Create a layout xml file called `image_tap_view.xml` (I think I might be wrong here)
3. Added `declare-stylable` to my **res/values/attrs.xml**

And I'm pretty confused. Right now in my `ListAdapter` I'm returning an `ImageView` in `getView()`. So now I'd like to return an `ImageTapView` instead but pass the `ImageView` into my `ImageTapView`. So my question is: **How do I pass this `ImageView` to the `ImageTapView`**?

Secondly, I'm pretty confused about the layout files. Right now in my `image_tap_view.xml` I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.mysite.ImageTapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#333333"
        custom:labelPosition="left"
        custom:showText="true"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Custom view Test"
            />

        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But it seems wrong to have my own custom view inside of my custom view layout xml. Wouldn't that cause an infinite loop? So my question is: **Where and how do I specify the layout for my new `ImageTapView`**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow!!!many question thinking where to start.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that! The Android dev docs kind of left me hanging. If there's a write-up somewhere from start to finish creating a custom view I'd happily accept that as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside xml just keep an `ImageView` and inside init function of your custom view inflate this xml and return it.

in getView create a new instance of custom view and return it.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#333333"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Custom view Test"
            />

        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Custom view:

```
public class ImageTapView extends LinearLayout{
    public ImageTapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }
      public ImageTapView(Context context){
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }
    private void init(Context context){
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml, this, true);
    }
    public void onClick(){

    }    

}
```

getView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageTapView view = (ImageTapView ) convertView;
    if (view == null)
        view = new ImageTapView (getContext());

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the right thing to do! I realized now that I'm getting a null pointer error, so I'll close this question and move on. Thanks again

Comment: If you do this, replace the <LinearLayout ...> with <merge...>, and you can save yourself an extra level of depth in your view hierarchy

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finished up the class as per your instructions and took your advice on using merge. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from what you posted, your ImageTapView needs to be a subclass (extends) View. Then in your class that returns getView it is possible for you to return the ImageTapView as it is still also technically a View.

For now see this : http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

In your `image_tap_view.xml` instead of having a `com.mysite.ImageTapView` you should just use the `ImageView` like you were before. In your `ImageTapView` class, when you need this `ImageView` component, simply create one and parse it from the xml.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#333333"
    custom:labelPosition="left"
    custom:showText="true"
    />

public class ImageTapView extends View {
public ImageTapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}
private void init(Context context){
     ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(//retrieve id set in xml);
}
public void onClick(){

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help so far! I'll post my custom class now~

Comment: @Prodikl Ive edited my answer to point you towards the android dev docs based on implementing a custom view. See if this can provide you some insight too.